# Solving ODEs in parallel in Julia: variable answers, hangs after several executions

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, julia, ode, sundials

I am using `Julia` `DifferentialEquations` on a large system of ODEs (127) that need to be solved repeatedly for different initial value vectors. I have found that `CVODE_BDF` is the fastest.

I'd like to send each ODE solve() to a different processor. However, I am getting puzzling behavior where the serial version of a function works, but the parallel version gets varying answers, & then hangs after being run a few times.

An example you can copy-paste to run is below. (Note: loads a file from gist which contains the pre-allocated indices & rate parameters for the ODE.)

```
using Dates                     # for e.g. DateTime, Dates.now()
using DifferentialEquations # for ODEProblem
using Sundials              # for CVODE_BDF

# Check that you have multiple threads
numthreads = Base.Threads.nthreads()

# Download & include() the pre-saved model structure/rates (all precalculated for speed; 1.8 MB)
#include("/GitHub/BioGeoJulia.jl/test/model_p_object.jl")
url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nmatzke/ed99ab8f5047794eb25e1fdbd5c43b37/raw/b3e6ddff784bd3521d089642092ba1e3830699c0/model_p_object.jl"
download(url,  "model_p_object.jl")
include("model_p_object.jl")
p_Es_v5 = load_ps_127();


# ODE to solve many times; @simd-enhanced version; 10+ times faster on a single core
ODE_to_solve_Ds_plain = (du,u,p,t) -> begin
  n = p.n
  mu = p.params.mu_vals
  Qij_vals = p.params.Qij_vals
  Cijk_vals = p.params.Cijk_vals
    # Pre-calculated solution of the Es
    uE = collect(repeat([0.0], 127)) # zero out the uE for now
    
  @inbounds for i in 1:n
        Qi_sub_i = p.p_TFs.Qi_sub_i[i]
        Qj_sub_i = p.p_TFs.Qj_sub_i[i]
        Qi_eq_i  = p.p_TFs.Qi_eq_i[i]
        Cj_sub_i = p.p_TFs.Cj_sub_i[i]
        Ck_sub_i = p.p_TFs.Ck_sub_i[i]
        Ci_eq_i  = p.p_TFs.Ci_eq_i[i]
        du[i] = -(sum(Cijk_vals[Ci_eq_i]) + sum(Qij_vals[Qi_eq_i]) + mu[i])*u[i] +  
            (sum(Qij_vals[Qi_eq_i] .* u[Qj_sub_i])) + 
            (sum(Cijk_vals[Ci_eq_i] .*                                               
                 (u[Ck_sub_i].*uE[Cj_sub_i] 
             .+ u[Cj_sub_i].*uE[Ck_sub_i]) ))
    end
end

# This is the core operation to solve "Ds"; plain version (no @simd)
function core_op_plain(u, tspan, p_Ds_v7)
    prob_Ds_v5 = DifferentialEquations.ODEProblem(ODE_to_solve_Ds_plain, u.+0.0, tspan, p_Ds_v7);
    sol_Ds_v5 = solve(prob_Ds_v5, CVODE_BDF(linear_solver=:GMRES), save_everystep=false, abstol=1e-12, reltol=1e-9);
    return sol_Ds_v5
end

# Do 8 solves in serial
function serial_solves_plain(tspan, p_Ds_v7, solve_results1; number_of_solves=8)
    start_time = Dates.now()
    for i in 1:number_of_solves
        solve_results1[i,:] .= 0.0
        solve_results1[i,i] = 1.0
        sol_Ds_v7 = core_op_plain(solve_results1[i,:], tspan, p_Ds_v7)
        solve_results1[i,:] .=  sol_Ds_v7.u[length(sol_Ds_v7.u)]
    end
    duration = (Dates.now() - start_time).value / 1000.0
    sum_of_solutions = sum(sum.(solve_results1))
    return (duration, sum_of_solutions)
end

# Do 8 solves in parallel
function parallel_solves_plain(tspan, p_Ds_v7, solve_results2; number_of_solves=8)
    print("\nSolved task #: ")
    start_time = Dates.now()
    # Make tasks, then run them
    tasks = Any[]
    tasks_fetched_TF = Bool[]
    for i in 1:number_of_solves
        solve_results2[i,i] = 1.0 
        # USING "PLAIN", NON-SIMD OPERATION HERE
        push!(tasks, Base.Threads.@spawn core_op_plain(solve_results2[i,:].+0.0, tspan, p_Ds_v7));
        push!(tasks_fetched_TF, false)
    end

    are_we_done = false;
    done_count = 0;
    while(are_we_done == false)
        for k in 1:number_of_solves
            if (istaskstarted(tasks[k]) == true) && (istaskdone(tasks[k]) == true) && (tasks_fetched_TF[k] == false)
                sol_Ds_v7 = fetch(tasks[k]);
                solve_results2[k,:] .= sol_Ds_v7.u[length(sol_Ds_v7.u)].+0.0
                done_count = done_count + 1;
                tasks_fetched_TF[k] = true
                print(k)
                print(" ")
                break
            end
        end
        if (done_count >= number_of_solves)
            are_we_done = true
            are_we_done && break
        end
    end
    duration = (Dates.now() - start_time).value / 1000;
    sum_of_solutions = sum(sum.(solve_results2));
    print("\n")
    return (duration, sum_of_solutions)
end

# Set up input; output objects
numstates = 127
number_of_solves = 8

solve_results1 = Array{Float64, 2}(undef, number_of_solves, numstates);
solve_results1 .= 0.0;
solve_results2 = Array{Float64, 2}(undef, number_of_solves, numstates);
solve_results2 .= 0.0;
size(solve_results1)

# Set up ODE Ds inputs
tspan = (0.0, 1.0)
p_Ds_v7 = (n=p_Es_v5.n, params=p_Es_v5.params, p_indices=p_Es_v5.p_indices, p_TFs=p_Es_v5.p_TFs, uE=p_Es_v5.uE, terms=p_Es_v5.terms);
p = p_Ds_v7;
tspan = (0.0, 1.0)

# Single solve operations for Ds; but solve() will be run many times
@time core_op_plain(u, tspan, p_Ds_v7);
@time core_op_plain(u, tspan, p_Ds_v7);

# Multiple ODE solves, serial versions
serial_solves_plain(tspan, p_Ds_v7, solve_results1; number_of_solves=number_of_solves)
serial_solves_plain(tspan, p_Ds_v7, solve_results1; number_of_solves=number_of_solves)
serial_solves_plain(tspan, p_Ds_v7, solve_results1; number_of_solves=number_of_solves)
#   (1.042, 7.048516354666927)
# (1.04, 7.048516354666927)
# (1.028, 7.048516354666927)

# Multiple ODE solves, parallel versions; answers differ
parallel_solves_plain(tspan, p_Ds_v7, solve_results2; number_of_solves=8)
parallel_solves_plain(tspan, p_Ds_v7, solve_results2; number_of_solves=8)
# Solved task #: 8 1 6 2 5 4 7 3 
# (0.331, 7.048516354666927)
# Solved task #: 8 1 6 2 5 4 7 3 
# (0.215, 7.680340772075006)


# Usually hangs on the 3rd try...
parallel_solves_plain(tspan, p_Ds_v7, solve_results2; number_of_solves=8)
# Hangs on:
# Solved task #:
```

Comment: I feel like this is a duplicate of somewhere else. For the parallel case, did you check for thread safety issues by doing a `deepcopy` of the arguments for `core_op_plain(solve_results2[i,:].+0.0, tspan, p_Ds_v7)`? You want to make sure you aren't mutating anything that is conserved between them, and that's the first way to make it obvious if you are.

Answer (score 1):

These aren't solving the same thing. In one case you do:

```
    solve_results1[i,:] .= 0.0
    solve_results1[i,i] = 1.0
    sol_Ds_v7 = core_op_plain(solve_results1[i,:], tspan, p_Ds_v7)
```

in the other you do

```
    solve_results2[i,i] = 1.0 
    # USING "PLAIN", NON-SIMD OPERATION HERE
    push!(tasks, Base.Threads.@spawn core_op_plain(solve_results2[i,:].+0.0, tspan, p_Ds_v7));
```

`solve_results2` is not zeroed before the run here, which is not the same as adding zero. This is why the first solve is correct, since you do `solve_results2 .= 0.0;` in the setup, so it's zeroed. But then after the first run it will have mutated and when you re-solve the initial condition is the solution of the last time.

That and a deepcopy of `p` makes it clearly thread safe. I haven't looked at this closely but if you use the same `p` object on multiple threads and they mutate the same `p`, then you will end up with one run effecting the parameters of the other. `deepcopy` will fix this the easy way, and the harder way is to make pre-thread caches so you don't collide the overwrites.